surjectivity of a function in a functional equation
Full statement
I don’t understand this implication in the first line:
$f((xf(0)+f(x))=f(0)+x$ means $f$ is surjective.

What is the definition of $P$?

Let P(x,y) denote the given assertion

You must clearly define from where $P$ and $f$ are mapped. Otherwise, we can, for example, choose the the image as the codomain of $f$, whereby $f$ is of course surjective. In your task, however, I would assume that $f$ is defined from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. Is that correct?

Let’s recall the definition of surjectivity. A function $g: X \rightarrow Y$ is surjective iff:
$$\forall y \in Y, \exists x \in X, g(x)=y$$
For this particular function (assuming its domain as $\mathbb{R}$), fix $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Let us show it has a preimage under $f$.
Well, $f(0)$ is just a number. Let $z=y-f(0)$. What is, in your terminology, $P(z,0)$? Clearly it is:
$$f((zf(0)+f(z))=f(0)+z=y$$
So $y$ has a preimage under $f$. Thus $f$ is a surjection. Does this make sense?

Let $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be an arbitrary function for which applies:
\begin{align}\forall x,y\in \mathbb R\colon f(xf(y)+f(x))=f(xy)+x.\label{gl1}\tag{1}\end{align}
We now want to show surjectivity. This means that for all $z\in \mathbb R$ we have $f^{-1}(\{z\})\neq \emptyset$ (i.e. $z$ has an preimage). Choose $x=z-f(0)$, thus:
$$f(xf(0)+f(x))\overset{\eqref{gl1}}=f(x\cdot 0)+x=f(0)+z-f(0)=z.$$
Thus $f$ is surjective, since $xf(0)+f(x)\in f^{-1}(\{z\})$.
